# MySql: Query select two dates having one month difference between

Tags: mysql

I have one column date in MySQL table with dates like-

```
01/01/2014
02/01/2014
05/01/2014
06/01/2014
25/04/2014
26/04/2014
27/04/2014
28/04/2014
29/09/2014
30/09/2014
01/10/2014
```

i need to select starting and ending dates having minimum 30 days difference between those dates like from above dates i would get

```
Starting Date   -      Ending Date

01/01/2014     -        06/01/2014

25/04/2014      -       28/04/2014

29/09/2014      -       01/10/2014
```

How can I do this in a MySQL select query?

Thanks

Comment: and if not having 30 days in between?

Comment: do you need to select all such pairs of dates? If you just need zero or one you could order by date and then check to see if the first and last are at least a month apart.

Comment: on basis of which date ?? i mean which date you will provide in your query?

Comment: This is SQL, so those are not really dates. Fix that, and try again.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT A.DateVal AS StartDate, B.DateVal AS EndDate
FROM TableName AS A, TableName AS B WHERE DATEDIFF(A.DateVal , B.DateVal) >= 30